# Cognito for identity and authentication only for a multi-tenant SaaS

Tags: amazon-cognito

We run a multi-tenant SaaS app, where orgs have users, and orgs are separated from each other.

This question follows this thread, which I have digested:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=819858

We have this scenario, similar to the thread above:

- *unlimited organizations*
- *unlimited users per organization*
- *unlimited "guests" as outside collaborators*
- *users within one organization cannot access anything in any other organization*

What is the solution to do this for unlimited organizations and unlimited users within each organization, given the limits published in the thread above?

*We only want to use Cognito to handle signup and signin for our SaaS.* We don't wish to use API Gateway, since we already use ALB behind our API instances.

Our problem is therefore identity and authentication, not authorization (e.g. permissions, roles, etc).

The reason for the unlimited guests requirement is because we are an app that enables a user to collaborate with others outside their company - see  https://tallyfy.com for context.

I'm confused about the best way to architect user pools, groups and/or just use attributes for this purpose. Help is appreciated.

Example solution - a single user pool with potentially millions of users, where a custom attribute of a user is "organization_id". Further, another custom attribute defines their user type within two types - *regular* or *guest*. Is this the ideal/workable solution?

Comment: Were you ever able to find an answer to this? I am interested in your findings.

Comment: @KFE sadly, not yet. We don't intend to jump in, for this reason. It seems that AWS is very much for one-off customers, and very much *not* for SaaS multi-tenant scenarios.